# understanding help/documentation in python

Tags: python

This might be a stupid question. I don't understand why the first one throws an error while the other one works. Is there a simple explanation here?

```
In[2]: import scipy
In[3]: help(scipy.optimize)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:.....lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
  File "<ipython-input-3-87bd9e5565b6>", line 1, in <module>
    help(scipy.optimize)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'optimize'



In[4]: from scipy import optimize
In[5]: help(optimize)
Help on package scipy.optimize in scipy:..........................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `help()`, importing it in a terminal yeilds the same result.

`scipy` is a package, `optimize` is a sub-package of `scipy`. In order for a module to be imported from a package it must be specified in the `__init__.py` file in the top level package `scipy`.

```
scipy -
       |- optimize
       |- __init.py__
```

It  does not so you must specify that it does exist by importing it directly.

```
import scipy
```

Gets `scipy` but it does not say in the `__init__.py` file `optimize` is part of it.  So it does not load it.

```
from scipy import optimize
```

Goes into `scipy` package and loads `optimize` without using the `__init__.py` file.  In other words you tell it to get `optimize` yourself.